# $u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{+};H^{1}(0,1))$ implies $||u(.,x)||_{L^{2}(0,1)}$ locally AC and Leibniz formula holds

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

My question is that if $u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{+};H^{1}(0,1))$, then do we have that the $L^2$ norm of $u$ : $t\mapsto ||u(t)||_{L^{2}(0,1)}$ is locally absolutely continuous, $u$ is locally absolutely continuous, for almost all $t\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $u(t,.)\in H^{1}(0,1)$, and the Leibniz formula holds almost everywhere, i.e. for almost all $t\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} ||u||_{L^{2}(0,1)} = 2||u \ \partial_{t}u||_{L^{2}(0,1)}$$
Intuitively, it seems like invoking the dominated convergence theorem is sufficient to prove it (since the Leibniz formula holds under some boundedness assumptions). However, I am not able to see how to use the DCT in this case. I wonder also if $u\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{+};H^{1}(0,1))$, for some $p\in [1,\infty)$ is not sufficient for what I said before to hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just give us the information about $u,u_{x}\in L^{2}(0,1)$, but no information about $u_{t}$. So we don't have the relation$$\frac{d}{dt}\|u\|_{L^{2}(0,1)}=2(u,u_{t})_{L^{2}(0,1)}$$. I think the reference "Navier-Stokes equations theory and numerical analysis" by Roger Temam, AMS CHELSEA PUBLISHING, chapter 3 can help you.

For convenience, I state the lemma of this book here : Let $V,H,V'$ be three Hilbert space, each space included in the following one as $V\subset H\sim H'\subset V'$,$V'$ being dual of $V$. If a function $u$ belongs to $L^{2}(0,T;V)$ and its derivative $u'$ belongs to $L^{2}(0,T;V')$ then $u$ is almost everywhere equal to a function continuous from $[0,T]$ into $H$ and we have the following equality, which holds in the scalar distribution sense on $(0,T)$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}|u|^{2}=2(u',u)_{V',V}.$$

In the case of $L^{p}$, I don't know what could happen.

Comment: Thank you very much ! So, following this lemma, if $u$ is solution (almost everywhere) to the PDE : $u_{t} = u_{x}$, and $u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0};H^{1}(0,1))$, then $u_{t}$ is in $L^2$ so by the Lemma, $u$ is continuous and we have the Leibniz formula. Is that right ? (I am assuming that in the lemma, $T$ can be infinity)

Comment: If T can be taken infinity, of course. your assertion is right. But I really don't know whether this lemma can take T=infinity, I'm sorry~. The material "Notes on Partial Differential Equations" by John K. Hunter may help you and you can refer to Appendix 6A of this material, you can "google" it and read the related part.

Comment: In the special example $u_{t}=u_{x}$, the solution of this equation exists on $R_{+}$. I think your assertion is right, not because T can be taken infinity, but T can be taken large enough so that any point $t$ can be controlled by $T$, the solution exists on the interval $[0,T]$, so we can use the lemma mentioned above. I really don't know this interpretation is enough, but I have tried my best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I think I am starting to understand how it works. So, let's say $u_{t} = u_{x} + f$, with $u\in L^{2}(0,T;H^{1}(a,b))$, and $f\in L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(a,b))$ (the spatial domain is $(a,b)$). Then, $u_{t}$ is in $L^{2}(0,T;L^{2}(a;b))$ (it follows the weaker space between $u_{x}$ and $f$), so I can apply Leibniz on $[0,T]$, and $||u||_{L^{2}(a,b)}$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,T]$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true, $u$ can be discontinuous like
$$
u(x,t) = \chi_{[0,+\infty)}(t).
$$

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I need more assumptions on $u$ (more precisely on $u_{t}$), like for e.g. being solution to some PDE.